# Hardhat Ethereum contract is missing address

Tags: ether, ethers.js, hardhat

Contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

// Uncomment this line to use console.log
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract BuyMeACoffee {
    // Event to emit when a memo is created
    event NewMemo(
        address indexed from,
        uint256 timestamp,
        string name,
        string message
    );

    // Memo struct.
    struct Memo {
        address from;
        uint256 timestamp;
        string name;
        string message;
    }

    // List of all memos received from friends.
    Memo[] memos;

    // Address of contract deployer.
    address payable owner;

    // Deploy logic
    constructor() {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    /**
     * @dev buy a coffee for contract owner
     * @param _name name of the coffee buyer
     * @param _message a nice message from the coffee buyer 
     */
    function buycoffee(string memory _name, string memory _message) public payable {
        require(msg.value > 0, "can't buy coffee with 0 eth");

        // Add memo to storage
        memos.push(Memo(
            msg.sender,
            block.timestamp,
            _name,
            _message
        ));

        // Emit a log event when a new memo is created!
        emit NewMemo(
            msg.sender,
            block.timestamp,
            _name,
            _message
        );
    }

    /**
     * @dev send entire blaance stored in contract to owner
     */
    function withdrawTips() public {
        require(owner.send(address(this).balance));
    }

    /**
     * @dev retrieve all memos stored on the blockchain
     */
    function getMemos() public view returns(Memo[] memory) {
        return memos;
    }
}
```

Hardhat script

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function getBalance(address) {
  const balanceBigInt = await hre.waffle.provider.getBalance(address);
  return hre.ethers.utils.formatEther(balanceBitInt);
}

async function printBalances(addresses) {
  let idx = 0;
  
  for (const address of addresses) {
    console.log(`Address ${idx} balance: `, await getBalance(address));
    idx++;
  }
}

async function printMemos(memos) {
  for (const memo of memos) {
    const timestamp = memo.timestamp;
    const tipper = memo.name;
    const tipperAddress = memo.from;
    const message = memo.message;
    console.log(`At ${timestamp}, ${tipper} (${tipperAddress}) said: "${message}"`);
  }
}

async function main() {
  const [owner, tipper, tipper2, tipper3] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

  const BuyMeACoffee = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("BuyMeACoffee");
  const buyMeACoffee = await BuyMeACoffee.deploy();

  await buyMeACoffee.waitForDeployment();
  console.log('BuyMeACoffee deployed to:', buyMeACoffee.address);

  const addresses = [owner.address, tipper.address, buyMeACoffee.address];
  console.log('== start ==');
  await printBalances(addresses);

  const tip = {value: hre.ethers.utils.parseEther("1")};
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(tipper).buyCoffee("Carolina", "You're the best!", tip);
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(tipper2).buyCoffee("Vitto", "Amazing teacher", tip);
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(tipper3).buyCoffee("Kay", "I love my Proof of Knowledge", tip);

  // Check balances after the coffee purchase.
  console.log("== bought coffee ==");
  await printBalances(addresses);

  // Withdraw.
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(owner).withdrawTips();

  // Check balances after withdrawal.
  console.log("== withdrawTips ==");
  await printBalances(addresses);

  // Check out the memos.
  console.log("== memos ==");
  const memos = await buyMeACoffee.getMemos();
  printMemos(memos);  
}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

Problem:

```
TypeError: no matching function (argument="key", value="address", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.6.0)
{
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  argument: 'key',
  value: 'address'
}
```

I'm not really sure what the issue is. Unfortunately, Hardhat docs aren't very illuminating. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
After using `getAddress()` the following error is thrown when trying to getBalance.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'provider')
    at getBalance (/Users/huwfulcher/projects/web3/BuyMeACoffee-contracts/scripts/buy-coffee.js:10:42)
    at printBalances (/Users/huwfulcher/projects/web3/BuyMeACoffee-contracts/scripts/buy-coffee.js:19:51)
    at main (/Users/huwfulcher/projects/web3/BuyMeACoffee-contracts/scripts/buy-coffee.js:45:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the ethers changed the way to access the address and V6 documentation [https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/contract/] says that should use `getAddress()` to retrieve it.

Changing `contract.address` to `await contract.getAddress()` should solve that issue.

Comment: Thanks that fixes that issue. From there on out though any other use of `getAddress()` even with an `await` throws an error saying undefined.

Comment: Could you share the error you are receiving? maybe it is not related to `getAddress`

Comment: Thanks, see my edit above

Comment: just to highlight, the new error is not due to using `getAddress()`, that was happening before using it. The problem should be that Waffle is not installed, try using ethers provider instead `await hre.ethers.provider.getBalance(address)`

Comment: there are more errors in the script, go over the ethers v6 to solve them. And there is also a typo, the buy me a coffee function is called `buycoffee` on the contract and `buyCoffee` on the script.

Comment: Solved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For others coming across this issue I have now resolved all of the code above to run correctly. Please see below. Thanks to Clau for providing support.

```
// We require the Hardhat Runtime Environment explicitly here. This is optional
// but useful for running the script in a standalone fashion through `node <script>`.
//
// You can also run a script with `npx hardhat run <script>`. If you do that, Hardhat
// will compile your contracts, add the Hardhat Runtime Environment's members to the
// global scope, and execute the script.
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function getBalance(address) {
  const balanceBigInt = await hre.ethers.provider.getBalance(address);
  return hre.ethers.formatEther(balanceBigInt);
}

async function printBalances(addresses) {
  let idx = 0;
  
  for (const address of addresses) {
    console.log(`Address ${idx} balance: `, await getBalance(address));
    idx++;
  }
}

async function printMemos(memos) {
  for (const memo of memos) {
    const timestamp = memo.timestamp;
    const tipper = memo.name;
    const tipperAddress = memo.from;
    const message = memo.message;
    console.log(`At ${timestamp}, ${tipper} (${tipperAddress}) said: "${message}"`);
  }
}

async function main() {
  const [owner, tipper, tipper2, tipper3] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

  const buyMeACoffee = await hre.ethers.deployContract("BuyMeACoffee");

  await buyMeACoffee.waitForDeployment();
  buyMeACoffeeAddress = await buyMeACoffee.getAddress();
  console.log('BuyMeACoffee deployed to:', buyMeACoffeeAddress);

  const addresses = [owner.getAddress(), tipper.getAddress(), buyMeACoffeeAddress];
  console.log('== start ==');
  await printBalances(addresses);

  const tip = {value: hre.ethers.parseEther("1")};
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(tipper).buyCoffee("Carolina", "You're the best!", tip);
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(tipper2).buyCoffee("Vitto", "Amazing teacher", tip);
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(tipper3).buyCoffee("Kay", "I love my Proof of Knowledge", tip);

  // Check balances after the coffee purchase.
  console.log("== bought coffee ==");
  await printBalances(addresses);

  // Withdraw.
  await buyMeACoffee.connect(owner).withdrawTips();

  // Check balances after withdrawal.
  console.log("== withdrawTips ==");
  await printBalances(addresses);

  // Check out the memos.
  console.log("== memos ==");
  const memos = await buyMeACoffee.getMemos();
  printMemos(memos);  
}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```